# Почему у меня на мой get запрос не выводится ответ сервера?

Tags: python, json, get

Почему у меня на мой get запрос не выводится ответ сервера?
Все параметры запроса написаны правильно, программа останавливается на моменте

```
timestamp=datetime.strptime(message['timestamp'], '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
      if timestamp > i:
        print(f">>> {message['user']}: {message['text']} ({message['timestamp']})\n")
        i = timestamp
      else:
        pass
```

Общий вид кода

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime, date, time

global i
i = datetime.strptime("0001-01-01 01:01:00", '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
while True:
  data = {'from_datetime': i}
  r = requests.get('http://xx.xx.xx.xx/getmessages' , params= data)
  global message
  for message in r.json():
    if not message:
      pass
    else:
      timestamp=datetime.strptime(message['timestamp'], '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
      if timestamp > i:
        print(f">>> {message['user']}: {message['text']} ({message['timestamp']})\n")
        i = timestamp
      else:
        pass
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/Рабочий стол/podklycheniye/text.py", line 10, in <module>
    for message in r.json():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 525, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Comment: Для начала напечатайте чему равен `timestamp` после стоки `timestamp=...`, вдруг там лажа какая-то.

Comment: Что содержит r.json() ? Смотрели?

Comment: @dtroyan <bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>

Comment: @CrazyElf до нее не доходит, останавливается на for message in r.json():

Comment: Нет, вы показали `.json` без скобок, а нужно `.json()`. Что выдаёт `print(r.json())`?

Comment: у тебя в коде есть 2 строки pass, замени их на print(1) и print(2) соответственно. и после цикла for тоже добавь принт, чтобы увидеть когда цикл завершился. потом запусти и покажи вывод

Comment: @CrazyElf Почему-то выводит ошибку, но он должен печатать. Если ввести r.text то печатает: [{'user': 'dfsf', 'text': 'ntrcn', 'timestamp': '2021-17-11 11:45:32'}]

Comment: @alex останавливается на строке: for message in r.json():

Comment: что значит "останавливается"? пожалуйста, добавь принты, что я попросил. запусти программу и покажи что она вывела на экран

Comment: @alex выводит ошибку и не идет дальше

Comment: какую ошибку!!??

Comment: отредактируй вопрос. добавь в него полный текст ошибки

Comment: Так же я заметил то, что при пустом json на сервере выводятся [], а когда на сервере что-то есть, то он почему-то отказывается работать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
area13@area13:~$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = "[{'user': 'dfsf', 'text': 'ntrcn', 'timestamp': '2021-17-11 11:45:32'}] "
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

проблема в том, что в ответе одинарные кавычки, а json использует двойные кавычки.

Решение? просто замените кавычки в ответе

```
>>> s.replace("'", '"')
'[{"user": "dfsf", "text": "ntrcn", "timestamp": "2021-17-11 11:45:32"}] '
>>> json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))
[{'user': 'dfsf', 'text': 'ntrcn', 'timestamp': '2021-17-11 11:45:32'}]
```

На всякий случай

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime, date, time

global i
i = datetime.strptime("0001-01-01 01:01:00", '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
while True:
  data = {'from_datetime': i}
  r = requests.get('http://xx.xx.xx.xx/getmessages' , params= data)
  global message
  for message in json.loads(r.text.replace("'", '"')):
    if not message:
      pass
    else:
      timestamp=datetime.strptime(message['timestamp'], '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
      if timestamp > i:
        print(f">>> {message['user']}: {message['text']} ({message['timestamp']})\n")
        i = timestamp
      else:
        pass
```

Comment: в каком ответе, где мне заменить ковычки?

Comment: @imadjf В `r.text` замените кавычки, а потом `json.loads` сделайте

Comment: @CrazyElf У меня нету r.text

Comment: @imadjf А кто писал в комментарии к вопросу: "Если ввести r.text то печатает ..."? Вот этот `r.text` и возьмите

Comment: Вот, теперь отлично ответ оформлен, только опечатки исправить и совсем хорошо )

Comment: Выходит новая ошибка!

Comment: я думаю ты уже и сам понимаешь что нужно делать